# Drop a div into another one and change its size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to drop a div into another one. When I do that I want the bigger div to be smaller and I want to call `alert ('div is here')`. The div with the class "test" should be dropped into the div with the the "ui-widget-content" and "draggable" classes. The div with the class "test" should be dropped into the div with classes "ui-widget-content" and "draggable". Here is the code:

CSS

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;;
  float: left;
}
/*
.draggable {
  width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
*/
.draggable { 
height: 100px;
width: 280px; 
    padding: 0.5em;

background-color: green; 
/*position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;

/* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);

/* rounded corners */
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px; 
border-radius: 7px;

/* gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
color-stop(0%, green), color-stop(15%, green), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, green 0%, green 0%, #D5E4F3 130%); 
}
.pgboody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}



.test {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 370px;   
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
        /* gradients - second red border, first red border, top white space, blue lines */
    background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), -o-repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-image:  linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .2), rgba(255,85,91, .2)), linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,85,91, .8), rgba(255,85,91, .8)), linear-gradient(top, white 0px, white 69px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70px), repeating-linear-gradient(white 0px, white 18px, #A6FFED 19px, white 20px);
    background-size: 1px, 1px, auto, auto 20px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y, no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: 90% 0px, 10% 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.test:first-line {
    line-height: 33px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.test:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

HTML

```
$(function() {
      $( "#student1" ).draggable();
      $( "#student2" ).draggable();
      $( "#student3" ).draggable();
        $( "#student4" ).draggable();

    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <ul class="">
      <li>
        <div  class="ui-widget-content draggable">
          <p>Student 1 </p>
          <div id="student1" class="test">
            this note from student 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
          <p>Student 2</p>
          <div id="student2" class="test">
            this note from student 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
          <p>Student 3</p>
          <div id="student3" class="test">
            this note from student 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div  class="ui-widget-content draggable">
          <p>Student 4</p>
          <div id="student4" class="test">
            this note from student 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>




      <div class="container">
        <div class="pgboody">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <ul class="">
        <li>
          <div  class="ui-widget-content draggable">
            <p>Student 5 </p>
            <!-- <div id="student5" class="test">
              this note from student 1
            </div> -->
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
            <p>Student 6</p>
            <!-- <div id="student6" class="test">
              this note from student 1
            </div> -->
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
            <p>Student 7</p>
            <!-- <div id="student7" class="test">
              this note from student 1
            </div> -->
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
            <p>Student 8</p>
            <!-- <div id="student8" class="test">
              this note from student 1
            </div> -->
          </div>
        </li>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </ul>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what your code provided does, what should we do with it? https://jsfiddle.net/5wwg1q5j/9/

Comment: i edited my question , i forgot css

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith any help ?

Comment: I am not clear on what you want, I get the `alert()` part, but what divs do you want to change?

Comment: the div `<div id="student1" class="test">
            this note from student 1
          </div>` i want to drag and drop it to the Student 2 div . and when i drop it , the size of it get smaller

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092771/jquery-drag-and-drop-checking-for-a-drop-outside-a-droppable